# Use Animated angular component as background

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following `app.component.ts` file:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">My Application</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<particles [style]="style" [width]="width" [height]="height" [params]="params"></particles>
```

Here I am trying to use the `<particles>` component to provide an animated background and I would like to be able to use the routing module outlet to enable whatever component is displayed to be shown on top of the `<particles>` component.

With the app routing to a default material design card, this is what I get:

[image]

How can I style the `<particles>` component and the `<router-outlet>` to ensure that the MdCard (or indeed what ever the router is pointing at) shows in front of the background.

Comment: Just set the z-index to be higher than the z-index of the `particles` component

Comment: OR by the structure of your document. If you are not using z-index everything that comes later in the document is displayed atop the once that come before it.

Comment: @user184994 I played around with Z-Index but didn't have any luck. See my example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aus7jk)

Comment: @DomenikReitzner See my comment above.

Comment: maybe try `z-index: -1;` should remove itself from the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
/deep/ .particles-container {
    background-color: #000051;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The position needs to be set to fixed so that it takes up the whole screen instead of sitting underneath your content

Here is a fork of your stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qf4pdp?file=src/app/app.component.css